# with_routing test helper doesn't work for integration tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Simple example that by all accounts *should* work:

```
require 'test_helper'

class FoosController < ApplicationController
  def index
    render plain: 'something'
  end
end

class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def test_some_routing
    with_routing do |set|
      set.draw do
        get '/foos' => 'foos#index'
      end

      get '/foos'
      assert_equal 200, response.status
    end
  end
end
```

Instead I'm getting: `ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [GET] "/foos"`

What am I doing wrong? This is latest Rails 4.1 btw.

Comment: Are you sure you have correctly defined controller in your routes? Like: `resources :foos`?

Comment: Idea of `with_routing` is to use routes defined in the block. So '/foos' clearly is defined. But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so I'm answering my own questions again. Problem is that `with_routing` doesn't work at all inside integration tests. Oversight or something, not sure. It only works for controller tests. So here's the work around:

```
class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def with_routing(&block)
    yield ComfortableMexicanSofa::Application.routes
  ensure
    ComfortableMexicanSofa::Application.routes_reloader.reload!
  end
end
```

Basically you will redefine your application routes within that block and then reload them back from the routes.rb file.

Answer (score 4):

For those who come here seeking a solution to test their controller concerns in isolation (like I did), it may pay to use `setup` and `teardown` blocks instead of littering your code with `with_routing` blocks:

```
require 'test_helper'

class ConcernedController < ApplicationController
  include Concern

  def action
    render plain: "response", status: :ok
  end
end

class ConcernTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @controller = ConcernedController.new

    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get "/action" => "concerned#action"
      post "/action" => "concerned#action"
    end
  end

  teardown do
    Rails.application.reload_routes!
  end

  test "concern method" do
    post "/action"

    # Test what the concern does

    assert_response :ok
    assert_equal "Response", response.body
  end
end
```

Tested against Rails 5.0.2.

Comment: This seems to erase all existing routes during the test run. So, if I want to check for a redirect to `signin_path`, I get a 500 error since that route is not defined.

Answer (score 1):

-- edited --
We can have a block with new routes by defining a new method like:

```
  def with_foo_route
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
      get 'foo' => 'foo#index'
    end
    yield
    Rails.application.routes_reloader.reload!
  end
```

And then execute a get requests to this new route by:

```
with_foo_route do
  get '/foo'
  assert_equal 200, status
end
```

Comment: You're not restoring routes to their initial state though. That `foos` path will be present in tests that run after.

Comment: That's true, its not an optimal solution.

Comment: We can restore the routes by running: Rails.application.routes_reloader.reload!